# Synonym for "thread-safe" when naming a class?

Tags: naming

Perhaps a silly question, but is there any common naming convention for a class that provides thread-safe operations, other than `ThreadSafeFoo`?  This is most explicit and works nicely, but I figured I'd ask if there are any single-word synonyms which represent the notion of thread safety ("Safe", "Locking"?), or if there's anything shorter that is commonly used?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166268/naming-general-purpose-thread-safe-data-structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Concurrent...` is a good choice. It describes very well the usecase in which it should be used without saying to much about technical details..

Answer (score 0):

SyncFoo can be a good choice to avoid too long class name.