# Naming (general purpose) thread-safe data structures?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, naming-conventions, naming

I'm looking for a good name to give to data structures that are thread safe / internally synchronized.

The C++ standard uses the term `atomic`, but [atomic has some rather special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356817/321013). Microsoft uses the term `Concurrent` in their [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) (or in C++ `_concurrent` in the [Parallel Containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx)).

What I really would like would be a generic wrapper for (value) types that provides a similar set of operations to what std::atomics do, but with a different name, and some typedefs derived from it. (use case: something like [std::atomic for std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876410/does-stdatomicstdstring-work-appropriately))

Which of the following would you consider useful / not useful and why?

- `SynchronizedThingamajig` (or `thingamajig_synchronized` or `synchronized_thingamajig`)
- `Concurrent...`
- `ThreadSafe...`
- `Safe...`
- `Parallel...`
- `Locked...`
- `Mutex` ... or `Mutexed...`
- `Multithreaded...`

For the string example I gave, maybe a `synchronized_string` or a `concurrent_string` would make most sense, or would that clash with any other connotation?

Comment: Both Microsoft PPL and Intel TBB use `concurrent_*`.  My only suggestion is: Don't use `parallel` when you mean `concurrent`.  (_Parallel_ is one kind of concurrency, but these data structures should work even on a single processor time-multiplexing multiple threads.)  You might also look at [`monitor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Useful answer from comment:

> Both Microsoft PPL and Intel TBB use `concurrent_*`. My only
>   suggestion is: Don't use parallel when you mean concurrent. (Parallel
>   is one kind of concurrency, but these data structures should work even
>   on a single processor time-multiplexing multiple threads.) You might
>   also look at the [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) pattern.

-- Wandering Logic Jun 18 at 12:02

To which I might add that from the choices I gave, after thinking some more about it, only `concurrent` and `synchronized` seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this name:

SafeContainer